# Подскажите идею для декстопного приложения

Tags: java

Добрый день. Есть желание стать сильнее в java. Хочу попросить подсказать идею приложения декстопного где в большей мере были бы необходимы разносторонние знания.

Comment: Я задавал подобный вопрос, посмотри, может найдешь что-то интересное из ответов: http://hashcode.ru/questions/175907/c-приложение-для-устройства-на-первую-работу

Comment: адресная кника это типичная задача что для десктопа что для консоли. как вариант пятнашки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **GTD органайзер** с синхронизацией с каким-нибудь сервисом. Прокачаете навык создания графических интерфейсов, работы с БД и работу с web.
2. **Оповещалку о новых вопросах на HashCode**. Опять же работа с веб, немного функций связанных со временем(интервал обновления) и трей. Такая программка обязательно должна быть в трее.
3. И мой любимый совет: напишите игру **"Жизнь" Конвея**. Она простенькая :) Тут Вам и массивы и работа с OpenGL(не обязательно)

И всё это обязательно с GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас думал и вот что пришло.
Сделай игру(клиент,сервер). Все рассылается вопрос или задача,они решают,кто раньше справился, тот и молодец.

Результаты записывай в бд.Сделай свой GUI.Вообщем примерно так.
Сервер тоже интересно,разные способы есть.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но с вебом пока не хочу связываться

Comment: Так и не делайте с вебом, сделайте любое клиент серверное приложение. Организуйте сокетное соединение и общение по средствам xml, если хотите сильно заморочиться шифруйте xml(например 7bit encoding).
Клиент должен обратится к серверу(например на localhost:43534), пройти авторизацию, потом отправлять и получать запросы/задания.
Сервер уметь определять и авторизировать клиента, отправлять и получать запросы/задания.

а там и что то типа чата можно сделать или удаленное управление или удаленный мониторинг ... что душа пожелает ;)

Comment: да, спасибо, как то не подумал

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду, но то что вы подумали первоначально тоже востребовано и интересно.